# Spritekit textured line drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skshapenode, sktexture

How to draw a texture line using `SKShapenode` in SpriteKit?

For example, how to draw chalk-like textured line on touch move?

Is the following method correct?

```
[lineNode setStrokeTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"texture.png"]];
```

But it shows nothing and the line is empty.

Comment: I tried a basic SKShapeNode textured line rect on the simulator and iOS device but both did not work. Either there's some step not included in the docs on how to achieve this or it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for your task is to use SKCropNode with the line node set as the mask node of the crop node and a texture node added as a child to the crop node. Keep in mind however, that SKCropNode does not use alpha value of the mask image pixels to "smoothly" mask out the target image. It just checks if the alpha of the mask image is greater than 0.05 and if so, displays the corresponding target image pixel and if not, it completely masks out the pixel. So the result may be somewhat pixelated.